# TDD Test first Nodejs express Rest Api - unit testing middlewere / controllers / routes

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, tdd

I'm trying to figure out how to test first my node js rest api app.
so far i've been using [nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) to intercept and mock any http call and by that test my service as a component. (component testing?)
i want to start unit testing my app so my test pyramid is more balanced and tests will be easier to write.

searching the web i got to this approach:
http://www.slideshare.net/morrissinger/unit-testing-express-middleware

```
var middleware = require('./middleware');
app.get('example/uri', function (req, res, next) {
  middleware.first(req, res)
    .then(function () { next(); })
    .catch(res.json)
    .done();
}, function (req, res, next) {
  middleware.second(req, res)
    .then(function () { next(); })
    .catch(res.json)
    .done();
});
```

(basicly pulling the middleware out and testing it)

since this presentation is from 2014 i was wondering what are the current up to date methods for unit testing express apps?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I used another approach.
First I created a file included in all my tests that start node and export a function to send an http request:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
var app = require('../server.js');

before(function() {
  server = app.listen(3002);
});

after(function(done) {
 server.close(done);
});

module.exports = {
  app: app,
  doHttpRequest: function(path, callback) {
    var options = {
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: 3002,
      path: path,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': 0
      }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, 
      function(response) {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');

        var data = '';
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
          data += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function() {
          callback(data, response.statusCode);
        });
      });

    req.end();     
  }
}
```

Then I called my server using the previous declared method:

```
var doHttpRequest = require('./global-setup.js').doHttpRequest;
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('status page test', function() {

  it('should render json', function(done){
    doHttpRequest('/status', function(response) {
      expect(JSON.parse(response).status).to.eql('OK');
      done();
    })
  });
});
```